# Code completion problem with Eclipse Galileo

Tags: eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I was trying 2 ROS packages which I created by myself. The strange thing is that one of them is having no problem with code completion while the other one cannot give any proposal. It just returns "ni default proposal" when I press "ctrl" and "spacebar". They are c++ anyway, both of them

Any idea?

-alfa-

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11372/code-completion-problem-with--eclipse-galileo/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2011-09-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One could be missing the proper #include statements in the header, the manifest could be missing dependencies, or you could be using the wrong namespace.

Additionally, if you've changed your manifest.xml, you may need to remake the Eclipse project. I find that I occasionally need to do this. I just navigate to that package on the commandline and issue a `make clean; make eclipse-project` command and restart Eclipse.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-09-29**:
Thank you very much..that helps a lot! The related workaround to remake the eclipse project is inevitable..